# Magento 2.2 soap api catalogInventoryStockRegistryV1UpdateStockItemBySku

Tags: magento2, upgrade, soap, stock

I'm trying to use Magento soap catalogInventoryStockRegistryV1UpdateStockItemBySku, but I cannot understand how parameters should be passed. I know there is REST documentation but if I apply the REST array of parameters to the soap call, it doesn't work.

So my question is: How can the catalogInventoryStockRegistryV1UpdateStockItemBySku api be used with soap? Alternatively, how can I update stock via soap?

Comment: Did you find solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution. Please see below my code change as per your need.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require('vendor/zendframework/zend-server/src/Client.php');
require('vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client.php');
require('vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client/Common.php');

$catalogProductRepositoryUrl = '<<your site url>>/soap/default?wsdl&services=catalogInventoryStockRegistryV1';
$token = '6n69tlvlu1pr5orjfkutgs817pw7eskp';

$options['stream_context'] = stream_context_create([
    'http' => [
        'header' => sprintf('Authorization: Bearer %s', $token)
    ]
]);

$soapClient = new SoapClient($catalogProductRepositoryUrl, $options);
$qtyData = [
    'qty' => 70,
    'isInStock' => 1,
    'isQtyDecimal' => 0,
    'showDefaultNotificationMessage' => 0,
    'useConfigMinQty' => 0,
    'minQty' => 2,
    'useConfigMinSaleQty' => 1,
    'minSaleQty' => 1,
    'useConfigMaxSaleQty' => 0,
    'maxSaleQty' => 10,
    'useConfigBackorders'  => 0,
    'backorders' => 1,
    'useConfigNotifyStockQty' => 0,
    'notifyStockQty' => 10,
    'useConfigQtyIncrements' => 1,
    'qtyIncrements' => 1,
    'useConfigEnableQtyInc' => 1,
    'enableQtyIncrements' => 1,
    'useConfigManageStock' => 1,
    'manageStock' => 1,
    'lowStockDate' => 1,
    'isDecimalDivided' => 1,
    'stockStatusChangedAuto' => 1
];

$response = $soapClient->catalogInventoryStockRegistryV1UpdateStockItemBySku(['productSku'=> 'F291', 'stockItem' => $qtyData]);
$result = $response->result;


echo '<pre>';print_r($result);exit;

?>
```

It's working fine. 
Still you have any query let me.

Comment: How to use this request in postman? getting err   
<faultstring>Procedure 'catalogInventoryStockRegistryV1UpdateStockItemBySku' not present</faultstring>